Proper way of running QProcess in a PySide6 app
I'm writing an app where I expect some routine tasks to be executed in background.
I want to create a class that would run in a QProcess.
Communication of QProcess with other instances would happen through QSignal interfaces.
Scenario:

Main class starts background process of video_stream and GUI app_window.
Main class also prints frame_cnt emitted from vide_stream QProcess.
VideoStream listens to video_stream_request QSignal and prints string on request.
Main class starts app_window, which has button to emit video_thread_request.
Both VideoStream and App instantiate CommonSignals with signals used for interprocess communication (created in singleton)

Issue:
VideoStream is emitting frame_available as expected but does not process incoming video_stream_request signal.
This can be only fixed by commenting out code where thread is being started:
self.moveToThread(self.thread)
self.thread.started.connect(self.process_video)
self.thread.start()

VideoStream process_video runs in QThread (no response to button click event):

VideoStream QThread is commented out:

Most likely way I'm trying to build the app is incorrect.
Would like to ask for any suggestion how to fix it.
Code:
import sys
import time

from PySide6.QtCore import QProcess, QObject, Slot, QThread
from PySide6.QtCore import Signal
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


def singleton(cls):
    """Singleton decorator for use on CommonSignals class."""
    instances = {}

    def get_instance(*args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        return instances[cls]

    return get_instance


@singleton
class CommonSignals(QObject):
    """QSignals class for communicating between instances."""
    video_stream_request = Signal()
    frame_available = Signal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


class VideoStream(QObject):
    
    def __init__(self):
        """Class with routine task in background that expects to receive outside requests time by time."""
        super().__init__()
        self.is_running = False

        self.process = None
        self.signals = CommonSignals()
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.frame_count = 0

        self.signals.video_stream_request.connect(self.receive_request)

    def start_process(self):
        """Starts the video capture in a separate QProcess."""
        self.process = QProcess(self)
        self.is_running = True

        # Move the processing function to the background
        self.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.process_video)
        self.thread.start()

    def process_video(self):
        while self.is_running:
            self.frame_count += 1
            self.signals.frame_available.emit(self.frame_count)
            time.sleep(1)
        self.thread.quit()

    @Slot()
    def receive_request(self):
        print(f"Request to VideoStream")


class App(QMainWindow):
    """GUI window that throws event to VideoStream via click of the button."""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 200)
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.button = QPushButton("video_thread_request", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.signals = CommonSignals()
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.emit_signal)

    def emit_signal(self):
        """Emit the custom signal when the button is clicked."""
        print("Button clicked, emitting signal.")
        self.signals.video_stream_request.emit()


class Main:
    """Main class."""
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        app = QApplication([])
        self.signals = CommonSignals()

        self.signals.frame_available.connect(self.print_frame_cnt)

        video_stream = VideoStream()
        video_stream.start_process()

        self.app_window = App()
        self.app_window.show()

        sys.exit(app.exec())

    def print_frame_cnt(self, cnt):
        print(f"frame_cnt: {cnt}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()



The thread is blocked by the while loop, therefore it cannot process signals. Try adding QApplication.processEvent() at the beginning (or the end) of while. If it still doesn't work, please [edit] your post and provide a more appropriate [mre] that doesn't involve unnecessary imports (just put all classes within a single code block) and ensure that it's actually runnable/reproducible (CommonSignals does not have a video_thread_request member).

Thanks for pointing out!
I've merged the code to single block.
However not sure how to apply your suggestion for while loop as video_stream class is an instance of QObject and does not have QApplication methods (?)

Just add QApplication.processEvents() as it's written (sorry, I missed the leading "s" in my comment above); processEvents() is a static function of QCoreApplication (therefore inherited by QApplication).

Whoa, it just works :D
Thank you very much for reaching out!
For me this issue seems to be solved.

Good for you! Just remember: when a slot is called, it blocks its thread's event loop until it returns. This means that everything connected to thread.started (assuming the connected slot is part of a QObject "moved" to that thread) will *block the event loop of the thread until that function returns, and since the started signal is connected to a function in the same QThread object, that results in blocking the event loop of that QThread, preventing it to process signals that are otherwise queued (as they're sent from another thread). processEvents() allows to process queued signals.
